# Qtp assumes ActiveX object as Winobject

Tags: automated-tests, qtp

[image]

Qtp assumes ActiveX object as WinObject. While using qtp with winobject program crashed. Am i doing anything wrong please help me to sort out the problem.

[image]

Also i have enabled smart identification in object identification box but there is no use.

Comment: Smart identification cannot help you here because it is just a refinement of the object recognition, but only once it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you load the ActiveX add-on when launching QTP.  Without it, ActiveX objects will be seen as WinObject.  As a general rule, also make sure you launch QTP before launching the application to ensure all necessary hooks are installed in the application's process.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [@HgCoder said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25203510/3848) (that you should load Active-X add-in and launch QTP first) you should configure QTP to inject the Active-X specific code into your application in the **Record and Run Settings** dialog.

You get to this dialog by the **Record** menu, then in the **Windows Applications** tab either select *Record and run test on any open Windows-based application* or add the specific application to the *Record and run only on:* option (the second option is preferred).